# EMI/UCP protocol: how to answer to a msg 52?

Tags: protocol, sms

`EMI` is a protocol to forward sms text data to a proxy provider (usually a telecom) that send them to end users.

I don't know how to give a positive ACK to a MSG52 (that is: a sms from an end user to my application). For example:

```
01/00098/O/52/3399903107/00393404679818/////////////140916144831////3//486920616C6C/////////////01
```

("hi all" from cell number 00393404679818)

I was trying:

```
01/00043/R/52/A//3399903107:140916144831/4B
```

as you see it a Response to a MSG52 with A (as ACK) and sm (the 7th) field as adc:scts.

What is wrong?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)